# my jsp code works only if i keep jars in Tomcat lib apart from lib folde in classpath

Tags: java, web-applications

In my application I am calling a bean from JSP and displaying data.I have kept all required jars in lib folder and that is in build path.When I run this bean it fetches the data successfully. But when I call this bean in JSP it says No Class defination.I found a workaround for this that is putting all the jars also in the lib folder of Tomcat.(apart from keeping in classpath). Means now i have to deploy the war and also put jars in tomcat lib.but why do i have to do this when jars are already in classpath.

thanks.

Comment: Where did you put your bean class?

Comment: Bean class is in the src...If i run this bean using a main it works fine..as it jars from lib class path.but if i call this bin in JSP it says classnotfound unless i add that in tomcat lib too

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be having a conflict with some of the jars. If one of the jars is depending on something provided elsewhere in the tomcat class loader, or if it is providing the same functionality - you could end up with a problem. You used to see this often with a conflicting XML parser implementations.

This has some more information on what is included: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html